# jquery AJAX load not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers seems to be able to help me. I'm using a bootstrap template to experiment with bootstrap, jquery, ajax, mqtt, etc.. I ran into ajax load and I want to use it. I'm trying to load the index.html page which contains:

> ## TEST
>
> test succesfull?

I test by clicking on the hallway menu item in the html code below (the one with the data-target="index" attribuut). The script (bottom of the html code) has some alerts in it which all work when I push the menu-item. It fetches the data-target as intended and executes the load. So far so good you'd think, but the test lines don't appear in the page-wrapper div...

- First is the js of the html template i'm using
- Second is the css code
- Third is the html code with at the bottom the js script I'm failing
  to get working.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

});

//Loads the correct sidebar on window load,
//collapses the sidebar on window resize.
// Sets the min-height of #page-wrapper to window size
$(function() {
  $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    topOffset = 50;
    width = (this.window.innerWidth > 0) ? this.window.innerWidth : this.screen.width;
    if (width < 768) {
      $('div.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
      topOffset = 100; // 2-row-menu
    } else {
      $('div.navbar-collapse').removeClass('collapse');
    }

    height = ((this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height) - 1;
    height = height - topOffset;
    if (height < 1) height = 1;
    if (height > topOffset) {
      $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
    }
  });

  var url = window.location;
  var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
  }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
  if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - SB Admin 2 Bootstrap Admin Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
#page-wrapper {
  padding: 0 15px;
  min-height: 568px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #page-wrapper {
    position: inherit;
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  }
}
.navbar-top-links {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-top-links li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-top-links li:last-child {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.navbar-top-links li a {
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  min-height: 0;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li a div {
  white-space: normal;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages,
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks,
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
  width: 310px;
  min-width: 0;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks {
  margin-left: -59px;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
  margin-left: -123px;
}
.navbar-top-links .dropdown-user {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-nav.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-search {
  padding: 15px;
}
.sidebar ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.sidebar ul li a.active {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.sidebar .arrow {
  float: right;
}
.sidebar .fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f104";
}
.sidebar .active>a>.fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f107";
}
.sidebar .nav-second-level li,
.sidebar .nav-third-level li {
  border-bottom: 0!important;
}
.sidebar .nav-second-level li a {
  padding-left: 37px;
}
.sidebar .nav-third-level li a {
  padding-left: 52px;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  .sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 51px;
  }
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages,
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks,
  .navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
.btn-outline {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.btn-primary.btn-outline {
  color: #428bca;
}
.btn-success.btn-outline {
  color: #5cb85c;
}
.btn-info.btn-outline {
  color: #5bc0de;
}
.btn-warning.btn-outline {
  color: #f0ad4e;
}
.btn-danger.btn-outline {
  color: #d9534f;
}
.btn-primary.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-success.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-info.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-warning.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-danger.btn-outline:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slidedown .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.login-panel {
  margin-top: 25%;
}
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
}
.btn-circle.btn-lg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}
.show-grid [class^=col-] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #eee!important;
}
.show-grid {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.huge {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.table {} .checkbox {} #sectionframe {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Home automation web page">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Home</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap toggle -->
  <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap-toggle-master/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
  <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-header -->

      <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">


        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <div>
                  <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> Failure
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted small">No respons from Controller 1</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
        </li>
        <!-- /.dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i>
          </a>
          <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
        </li>
        <!-- /.dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.dropdown -->
      </ul>
      <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

      <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="index"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> House<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Weather</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Energy</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Water</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> 1st floor<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav nav-second-level" id="side-menu2">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" data-target="index">Hallway</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Main bedroom</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> main floor<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Kitchen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Living room</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Garage</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Basement</a> 
              <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></i> Garden</a> 
              <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>

    <div id="page-wrapper">

    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Toggle JavaScript -->
  <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-toggle-master/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Domotica JavaScript -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Set trigger and container variables
      var trigger = $('#side-menu li ul li a'),
        container = $('#page-wrapper');

      // Fire on click
      trigger.on('click', function() {
        alert("click detected");
        // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
        var $this = $(this),
          target = $this.data('target');
        alert("target: " + target)
          // Load target page into container
        container.load(target + '.html');
        alert("load completed")
          // Stop normal link behavior
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does annyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting all the alerts of the javascript (so it is being run and it gets the index data attribute perfectly) but there just doesn't appear any text in the container..
*testing with google chrome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine ... you might just need to set the correct PATH to your ajax request. Also make sure you are not hitting some Access-Control-Allow-Origin block.

And you should change this:

```
container.load(target + '.html');
alert("load completed"); //not true
```

To this:

```
container.load(target + '.html', function (response, status, xhr) {
  alert("load completed"); 
});
```

So you can use "alert(response)" in the callback to check if it works.

[Jsbin with your code working](http://jsbin.com/wukege/edit?js,output)

Also make sure you've setup a local server like XAMP, Apache or nodejs

Comment: the html file that should load is in the same folder as the posted html file, so there's no need to add a path right? I updated the code and it's still not working. So an Access-Control-Allow-Origin block maybe?

Comment: what the console (f12) tells you?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Documenten/Arduino/02%20-%20eigen%20projecten/mqtt%20arduino%20-%20raspberry%20pi/webpagina%20rpi/pages/index.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. I'm quite new to html, css, ajax and stuff should have found this error message earlier

Comment: the path begins with "file://" ... that means you did not setup a local server and your borwser is trying it's best to use the operational system as a static server. Ajax calls (or XMLHttpRequests) will work this way and require a proper server. Try out XAMP, apache, nodejs or whatever fits you best.